# ajax login. The Form in a controller equals nothing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following fom:

```
form id="login_form" class="fancy_form" action="@Url.Action("Logon", "Account")" method="POST">
    <div class="bl_label">
        Eneter by login:</div>
    <div style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <div class="wrap_input" style="display: inline-block;">
            <p class="inp_label">
                Login:</p>
            <i>&nbsp;</i>
            <input type="text" value="" style="width: 131px">
        </div>
        <div class="wrap_input" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 15px;">
            <p class="inp_label">
                Password:</p>
            <i>&nbsp;</i>
            <input type="password" value="" style="width: 131px">
        </div>
        <div id="error">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 17px 30px 0px 30px; line-height: 20px;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="margin-right: 20px;">Forgot Password?</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);">
            Register?</a>
        <input type="submit" class="ibtn" value="Готово" style="float: right;">
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my script:

```
 $("#login_form").live("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            // Get the action URL
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",

            // get all form variables
            data: form.serialize(),

            // upon success, the fragment of HTML from the Controller will be stored in loginResultHtml
            success: function (loginResultHtml) {

                // append the html to your login DIV id using jQuery.html function
                $("#error").html(loginResultHtml);
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller for test:

```
public JsonResult LogOn()
        {
            var test = Request.Form;
            return new JsonResult();
        }
```

The `Form` property in the `Request` contain nothing (`Count` = 0, `AllKeys` is empty)
Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input elements are missing the "name" attribute.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp
Quote:

> **Note:** Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

You should consider using the html helpers which help you create correct HTML code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx